# Install new kernel in PowerPC debian 

Tags: debian, kernel, system-installation, powerpc

I compiled a new kernel image on x86 using cross compiler with these commands ([source](http://www.thebitsource.com/programming-software-development/how-to-install-debian-linux-on-an-embedded-system/)):

```
$ cp arch/powerpc/configs/pmac32_defconfig .config
$ make ARCH=powerpc menuconfig
$ make ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=pwoerpc-750-linux-gnu-
```

Now, I want to install this new image on a debian-powerpc. Debian-powerpc uses quik as the default bootloader. How do I do that?

Comment: ...so you followed the instructions for quik and it worked?  Didn't work?  How far did you get?

Comment: In Debian you should use the package `kernel-package` for manage the custom kernels. The tool `make-kpkg` make a .deb with your custom kernel. About the bootloader, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have cross compiled your packages, copy them to your PPC machine and install them via `dpkg`. They already contain the required code in order to update your bootloader (if required). Some bootloaders only use `/vmlinuz` link, so you don't even have to update anything.

My Debian PowerPC machine uses yaboot as a bootloader, and I do not have to do anything when updating kernel. For quik, check your `/etc/quik.conf` and verify that your `image=`*path* contains the right kernel path. Otherwise change it and then run the `quikconfig` command.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Debian up and running now on the system?  If so, you could copy the existing config from `/boot/config-<kernel version>` to your kernel source directory and use that as a starting point.  You can open that with `make xconfig` and edit it to suit your needs.